# Unable to define properties which start with keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

Unable to define properties which start with keycloak. keycloak-spring-boot-starter starter jar fails to load the properties if it observes keycloak properties which aren't known to the jar. The issue gets resolved if we prefix "`sso`" to the properties, is there a way to avoid this error even when keeping the keycloak prefixes.

```
keycloak.admin.username=
keycloak.admin.password=

sso.keycloak.admin.username=
sso.keycloak.admin.password=
```

this is the error seen with `Spring Boot 2.5.0 and Keycloak 13.0.0`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.addFilterAtOffsetOf(HttpSecurity.java:2654)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.addFilterAfter(HttpSecurity.java:2645)
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:123)
        at com.foo.config.KeycloakSecurityConfig.configure(KeycloakSecurityConfig.java:36)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:217)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:93)
        at com.foo.config.KeycloakSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$501f46fb.init(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error was introduced in version **5.5.0 of Spring Security** which comes with **Spring Boot 2.5.0**.
This is happening because KeyCloak adds two filters successively after another, like this:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                ...
                .addFilterAfter(keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter(), SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(keycloakAuthenticatedActionsRequestFilter(), KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.class)
                ...
}
```

And there's a bug right now in which the custom filter order is not being persisted, thus resulting in a `NullPointerException` when trying to add a filter relative to another custom filter recently added.

What I advise you to do right now is to use a lower version of Spring Boot, like 2.4.x until the [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9787) gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

From the Keycloak code it seems they have hardwired the properties to specific properties only.

From KeycloakSpringBootProperties

> /* this is a dummy property to avoid re-rebinding problem with
> property keycloak.config.resolver
> when using spring cloud - see KEYCLOAK-2977 */

From their code, its seems we can make use of a workaround they have to include additional properties.
But to do that we have to add 'config' in it.

```
keycloak.config.admin.username=asd
keycloak.config.admin.password=sss
```